# Не могу прописать java class в public void

Tags: android

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
String abc = "Hello";
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Function(abc)//При нажатии удачно ставится string
                }
            }
.
.
.
public void Function(String s){
    textView.setText(s)
}
```

С обычным `string` всё происходит идеально, но
когда хочу брать `string array` с какого-то java класса, к примеру так

Database.java

```
public class Database {
    private String[] dialog1 = {
            "Russian", "English", "Kazakh"
    };
    public String dialog1(int a) {
        return dialog1[a];
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
private Database data = new Database();
int a = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Function(data.dialog1(a))//Но здесь уже не находит data string
                }
            }
public void Function(Class.String(int a)){
   a++;
   textView.setText(Class.String(a))
}
```

Comment: В анонимных классах внешние переменные могут быть только final, таково ограничение Java

Comment: Вы уверены что `Function` точно должен принимать на вход `Class.String(int a)`, а не всем привычный `String string`, как это сделано в 1 варианте метода?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Function(new Database().dialog1(a));
}
```

Comment: Бессмысленно использовать анонимный экземпляр класса, когда используется именованный, и при этом дело не в нём